# perform diffrent task on listview button click

Tags: android, listview, button, click

I am having a issue.

```
       listview position 1
       button1
       listview position 2
       button2
```

This is my designof listview . My adapter is as follow

```
       adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.appareal_listview_text ,cursor, new String[]{"Key_ProductName","Key_SellingPrice"} , new int[] {R.id.title_info_txt_v,R.id.description_info_txt_v});
```

Now i am giving my xml file appareal_listview_text.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:clickable="true"
   android:background="@drawable/layout1"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_info_txt_v"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dip"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description_info_txt_v"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBuyNow_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buynow"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="buynowClick" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now my porblem is that define my button in xml which is call by adapter and button is define only i just once in xml , and i want to perform different task on each click of each position of listview.For that i used

```
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, asasdad.class);
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);
        intent.putExtra("EMPLOYEE_ID", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
        startActivity(intent);
        System.out.println("list is click");
    }
```

and as well as i can not use this

```
       listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text

       }
});
```

So how i will recognize which list button position is clicked to perform different task.

Comment: problem solved or still facing?

Comment: @Chintan ..Thanks for curiosity in my problem,,,i am still same problem

Comment: You should go for searching children from view when item is selected.

Comment: @ChintanRathod thanks for help in search key word.you are really helpful man....

Answer (score 0):

You should use following code.

```
button.setTag("position");
```

When button clicked,

```
String strPos = view.getTag();
```

Here you will get position of button.

Comment: ok i tried this , but how i will implement this even button and click is define xml.

Comment: @BlueGreen, you can't because you need to implement in your Adapter of list view. You need to create a `separate class of adapter` where "getView" method override. In your code, you can get position as well view where it is clicked. Pardon if i get you wrong.